# prefect loop over flows: two schedules

Tags: python, etl, prefect

I have a specific ETL problem: in my case data comes from a paginated resource, and can be fetched by pages of fixed size. So the call to the API specifies page 1, page 2, page 3 etc.
According to my plan each page is then transformed and loaded.
So an ETL of a page is an `etl_batch` flow (of atomic (page)tasks), but then I would like to run ETL over the whole paginated resource, until the last available page. So I thought this should be solved by a flow with a loop (called every hour, for example) over `etl_batch` flows (called every couple of seconds). Based on references below I realized the model has to be cast as a flow of a task of (page)flows of (page)tasks.

[docs.prefect.io/core/advanced_tutorials/task-looping.html](https://docs.prefect.io/core/advanced_tutorials/task-looping.html)

[stackoverflow.com/questions/68103561/looping-tasks-in-prefect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68103561/looping-tasks-in-prefect)

Here's the issue I encountered : if I specify the schedule for `etl_batch` flow its state appears to be reset.
But I comment out `etl_batch` flow schedule `schedule_every_second`, then the loop is working correctly, i.e `page` is incremented (please see the snippet below). However, for this ETL pipeline it is important to run `etl_batch` flow and (page)tasks on schedule due to possible saturation of the API.

I assume the problem is due to the fact that cache is being cleared when `etl_batch` flow is run on schedule (I tried to insert `cache_for=` here and there to no avail). Do you have any suggestions?

```py
from datetime import timedelta
from prefect import task, Flow, context, Parameter
from prefect.schedules import IntervalSchedule
from prefect.engine.signals import LOOP

schedule = IntervalSchedule(
    start_date=None,
    interval=timedelta(seconds=3),
)

schedule_every_second = IntervalSchedule(
    start_date=None,
    interval=timedelta(seconds=1),
)


@task
def next_page(page):
    print(f" {page}")
    return page + 1

@task
def paginate():
    current_page = context.get("task_loop_result", 1)
    with Flow('etl_batch',
              # schedule=schedule_every_second
              ) as flow:
        x = Parameter('x')
        add = next_page(x)
    state = flow.run(parameters={'x': current_page})
    nr = state.result[add]._result.value

    if nr > 3:
        return nr
    raise LOOP(result=nr)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Flow("etl", schedule=schedule) as etl_flow:
        r = paginate()
    f = etl_flow.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use both task looping and a scheduled flow together to fetch from your external resource multiple times. You should only need one. You should use task looping to iterate a task `n` times. Reasons below.

Calling `flow.run()` on a scheduled flow will run infinitely, your program never moves forward from the line `flow.run(parameters={'x': current_page})` is called. The surrounding task isn't looping at all. You are just calling the same flow with the same `x=current_page` value over and over again, on a schedule.

You should remove the schedule from your sub flow, and simply use `time.sleep(1)` to enforce a waiting period. Then you can use loop results to collect your paginated resources, as described

Comment: Thank for your answer. It's clear why the program is not moving forward. And indeed I resorted to using  `time.sleep` for the moment, however, I am not completely satisfied with this solution, it seems that there should be  a `prefect`-native solution. What if the parameter of `time.sleep` has to be changed at some point?

Comment: in that case you could also include the waiting time as a flow Parameter :) I'll respond via Slack since you cross-posted there